# finding a function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(2x+1) = 3f(x)+5$. Why does the recursion solution apply for a continuous variable?

Tags: functions, recursion

Find a function mapping from the real number line to itself such that $f(2x+1) = 3f(x)+5 \space\space\space\space\forall x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ provided that $f(0) = 0$.

I ran through a solution of this problem with a recursion. Let:

$a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1$

$b_{n+1} = 3b_n + 5$

Note that $f(a_{n}) = b_n$

$f(0) = 0$ demands that $a_0 = b_0 = 0$

$a_1 = 1$

$a_2 = 1 + 2$

$a_3 = 1 + 2 +4$

from which we can see:

$a_n = 2^n - 1$

A similar argument can be made for $b_n$ to get:

$b_n = \frac{5}{2}(3^n-1) $

Noting that $x = a_n$, we get that:

$n = \frac{ln(x+1)}{ln(2)}$, so that

$f(x) = \frac{5}{2}(3^{\frac{ln(x+1)}{ln(2)}} -1) $

to make it work for $x \le -1$, we just take the absolute value of the argument.

$f(x) = \frac{5}{2}(3^{\frac{ln(|x+1|)}{ln(2)}} -1) $

This function can be easily checked to satisfy the the original equation, so it is a solution. I understand the methodology of this argument quite well, but am somewhat flustered over the idea that we can write a discrete recursion for a continuous variable and still obtain a solution for *all* $x$. In some ways, it seems appropriate, as we *do* have an infinite number of values for which the solution is valid (i.e. all values $2^n - 1$ for an integer $n$), but it seems a little handwavy to me. I see that we essentially convert $n$ to a continuous variable by letting $a_n=x$, but why exactly is this valid?

Comment: Note that the expression you derived for $f(x)$ only holds true when $\log_2(x+1) \in \mathbb{N}$. It just happened that the expression had a natural extension to $\mathbb{R}$ which also satisfied the original relation for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I entirely agree with that; which is part of my confusion. Why is it that this natural extension to $\mathbb{R}$ exists here? I can't imagine that this argument would hold for all functions.

Comment: The function $f$ solves this if and only if the function $g$ defined by $$g(x)=f(x-1)+\tfrac52$$ solves $$g(2x)=3g(x)\qquad g(1)=\tfrac52$$ if and only if the function $h$ defined for every $x\ne0$ by $$h(x)=|x|^{-\log3/\log2}g(x)$$ solves $$h(2x)=h(x)\qquad h(1)=\tfrac52$$ if and only if the functions $m_\pm$ defined for every $x\ne0$ by $$m_\pm(x)=h(\pm e^x)$$ are both periodic with period $\log2$ and such that $m_+(0)=\tfrac52$. Thus, the solutions $f$ on $x>-1$ and on $x<-1$ are unrelated but, ...

Comment: ... on $x>-1$, $$f(x)=(x+1)^{\log_23}\left(\ell(\log_2(x+1))+\tfrac52\right)-\tfrac52$$ where $\ell$ can be any function of period $1$ such that $\ell(0)=0$.